# Stop closing of modal on outside click in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap for modal component.

Here is my importing code.

```
import React from "react";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import ModalBody from "react-bootstrap/ModalBody";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

The current behavior of modal is when someone clicks outside of the modal-content. It gets automatically closed. I want to stop this behavior. I tried with a number of ways which were suggested in Stack Overflow posts but failed to do so.

**Modal Code**

```
<Modal data-backdrop="static" shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false} data-keyboard="false" show={this.state.modalIsOpen} onHide={this.toggleModal} id={this.props.modalId} centered>
        <ModalBody style={style}>
            <h3 className="heading color-white">Please Wait</h3>
            <CustomLoader />

        </ModalBody>
      </Modal>
```

Comment: try removing `data-` from the `data-backdrop="static"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your props for Modal are wrong, Modal component has a prop called backdrop="static" to change behavior on backdrop click:

```
<Modal
    show={show}
    onHide={handleClose}
    backdrop="static"
    keyboard={false}>
</Modal>
```